# Calling Non sync method from sync method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In Java, if a non synchronized method is called only from a synchronized method and while the thread is executing the non synch method, the synchronized method is called from another thread. Will this second thread be able to call the non sync method. According to my knowledge, the second thread shouldn't even be able to call the sync method because that method hasn't returned yet. However I am still asking this question to clear my confusion.

Regards

Comment: Is the second call to the synchronized method on the same instance as the first call to the synchronized method?

Comment: yes it on the same instance of the class. Basically I am calling inside the sync and non sync methods inside the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this second thread be able to call the non sync method?

No. In fact, that second thread would not be able to enter the synchronized section of the method at all, until the first thread is done with it.

Of course the second thread would be able to call the non-synchronized method directly, but you mentioned that it never happens, so you are OK.

It goes without saying that in case of instance methods the calls to the synchronized method happen on the same instance.

Comment: I mentioned that the non sync method is not called directly but it is called from inside the sync method

Comment: @Naruto Yes, I acknowledged that part inside the answer.